# Is it possible to acces a table storage in Azure from an Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I would like to use the Azure Table Storage Service from an Azure Web Site (not a Cloud Service). There is guides on how to do this using Node.js but I like to use .NET MVC instead.

All the guides for .NET talks about storing the Azure Storage connection information in the ServiceConfiguration (as you do in a Cloud Service) but in an Azure Web site I do not have this (just a Web.config). If I am not mistaken it is also not possible to use the RoleEnvironment (used to read from the ServiceConfiguration) without running in the Azure emulator and I do not do this in an AzureWeb Site.

Is it possible to access the Table Storage from an Azure Web Site and if so how do I connect to it?

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587795/can-azure-table-be-accessed-from-web-site) and it does not look similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply get the connection string from the web.config and parse it (note that you can also use the `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` method):

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myStorageAccountConnectionString"];
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

And in your web.config you will need to add the connection string like this:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myStorageAccountConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=fazfazefazefzeefazeefazfazefazef"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Thanks, for me that was not obvious looking at the guides. Is it also possible to use the local development storage (by setting UseDevelopmentStorage=true and somehow start the Azure Emulator)?

Comment: Yes. You can start the storage emulator like this: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe /devstore:start`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes. Table Service has a [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/dd179423.aspx), which means you can access it from any client platform that can communicate over http.

Googling then produces tons of examples:

http://azure.snagy.name/blog/?p=294

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/09/20/azure-table-storage.aspx

You can use the `CloudTableClient` from MVC: even if most examples are for Cloud Services, you can easily tweak them to get connection data from web.config, or from any other source. How-to docs are here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/